How to save changes to patch files for kernel headers in `include/linux` using `diff`?
I am trying to hack the Linux kernel and added/modified some header files in include/linux. However, when I generate patch file using diff like:
diff -uprN -X linux/Documentation/dontdiff \
        linux-5.15 linux-srctree > patch.p1

I find changes under include/linux not included in patch.p1. I then look into dontdiff file and find the following lines (around line 158), which means it excludes include/linux from the patch file.
*lex.*.c
linux
logo_*.c

So why does dontdiff include linux? How to save changes to patch files for headers in include/linux? Thanks a lot.

Kernel patches are usually produced by git — changes are made in the working tree, and git diff used there, or committed and then extracted from the commit(s) with git format-patch. So dontdiff probably isn’t used much; exclusions are handed by .gitignore, which is more expressive than lists of patterns for diff -X.
In your scenario, the simplest option is probably to remove the linux line from dontdiff. Longer term, if at all possible, try working in a clone of the relevant git repository and produce your patches using git.
I suspect the reason linux is included in dontdiff is that the build process can produce a binary called linux (usually it’s vmlinux, but the um “arch” links that to linux). The .gitignore entry was added for arch/um, and modified later on to apply only to the root of the tree along with several other entries.

Thanks a lot. In my case I make modifications based on an existing source tree which didn't use git for tracking changes. So I want to use diff to generate a patch file and apply it on a clean source tree to use git version control.
I found a document in an early version (v4.x) and it guides me to generate patch file manually with diff. But dontdiff file does actually miss the include/linux, which is fixed in .gitignore.

Maybe diff/patch method has been deprecated even earlier. There is a "obsolete" note in the document about patch in v4.x.
